# JSF template not applied

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm running into a problem with JSF and templating. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.itinpractice.com/tutorials/76/jsf2-ui-insert-ui-define-ui-include-ui-composition.html#.UcSaXD6OMql) but the only output I see is the one I'm defining in my index.xhtml with

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
my custom content
</ui:define>
```

without adding the footer and header even though I'm not defining/overwriting the default one in my index file.

If I view the source in the browser it's showing up the same way as in my index.xhtml with `ui:composition` etc. So it looks like it's not "converting" it to HTML.

The relevant parts of my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <description>Controller Servlet for data input</description>
    <display-name>InputServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>InputServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>form.controller.InputServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InputServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My directory structure looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0vsz.png

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about your `InputServlet` config or so, but where's the `Faces Servlet` configuration? Besides of that, I guess you must use `*.xhtml` as url pattern instead of `*.jsf` since you're using xhtml extension to access to your files since your `<ui:composition>` uses  an XHTML page.

Comment: Thanks, i changed the jsf/xhtml url pattern. I'm not sure about the Faces Servlet configuration. I'm just using the one Eclipse generated for me. It looks like this: http://pastebin.com/tBTuJmry (Sorry for the Pastebin, it's a bit too long to add to the comments.

Comment: It would be better reading a nice tutorial about JSF instead of blindly trusting in the IDE's autogenerated code. It's good that IDE helps you with productivity code, but never blindly trust in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong servlet.

JSF comes with its own servlet, the `FacesServlet`.

Get rid of the `InputServlet` from `web.xml` altogether and map JSF's `FacesServlet` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That should do it.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - contains a Hello World and several links to sane tutorials

Comment: If you look in comments 2 hours ago, there is a [link](http://pastebin.com/tBTuJmry) that show entire web.xml and it looks like it is already configured.

Comment: @Alex: he configured it wrongly. As answered, the input servlet must be removed and the faces servlet must be mapped on `*.xhtml` (so that the welcome file is properly presented).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually just "solved" it myself by reading up on how to configure the web.xml and just came here to post my solution which is exactly the same as the one you came up with and now it's working just fine. (Thanks for the JSF Wiki page!)